# Why can't I retrieve Date time value from my database in Django orm?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have the following scenario:

in models.py

```
def Lab(models.Model):
    test_id=models.IntegerField()
    test_name=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    test_date=models.DateField()
```

I migrated the DB to sqlite3 and filled it from an external Excel sheet, now I am trying to do the following:

```
Lab.objects.values_list('test_date',flat=True)
```

This call raises the following error

> *** ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'09 00:00:00.000000'

I can simply ask for the other values and have no problem but not for test_date value, What could be the mistake here?

### Update

As pointed out, I manually filled the table using the following code snippet:

```
df['test_date'] = df['test_date'].astype(str)
df['test_date'] = df['test_date'].replace('0', np.nan)
str_date = df['test_date'].str.zfill(8)
df['test_date'] = pd.to_datetime(str_date,  yearfirst=True, format='%Y%m%d')`
```

then I filled it to the DB as

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///db.sqlite3', echo=False)
df.to_sql('Lab', con=engine, index=False, if_exists='append')
```

Comment: You should show how you populated the database. Apparently you have imported that column as a string, not a date.

Comment: I have formated the data in a pandas dataframe as datetime, then I did put it in the DB

Comment: **Show the import code** along with the sample data. Sqlite doesn't validate data types, so it's perfectly possible to insert a string into a date column, which is apparently what you have done.

Comment: Please see the updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that Pandas has inserted your `test_date` column as a datetime, not a plain date - so there is extra data on the end of the value that Django doesn't know what to do with.

I'm far from an expert on Pandas but I believe it would work if you explicitly specified the test_date field as a Date:

```
from sqlalchemy.types import Date
df.to_sql('Lab', con=engine, dtype={"test_date": Date()}, if_exists='append')
```

Comment: Thanks, your note was right, when I wrote with to_sql using pandas, it wrote also the time which should not be in a Datefield. I just removed it and it worked. I also tested your way and it is also valid. Thanks for the great remarks :)

Answer (score 0):

update your query if you want to apply some filters:

```
Lab.objects.filter(test_id=1).values_list('test_date',flat=True)
```

or if you want all data:

```
Lab.objects.all().values_list('test_date',flat=True)
```

Comment: I tried Lab.objects.all().values_list('test_date', flat=true) and it does not appear to work. I have the same failure out.

Comment: By the way, I need to retrieve all column values in test_date